# How to adapt the section dots in the ToC?

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to have my figures, sections, etc. numbered like 1.1. (instead of 1.1). So I would like to have an extra dot at the end of each number. With the MWE below, I could get that, but in the ToC the extra dot is not present. To make it a bit more complicated: for the chapter I would like to have the extra dot present in the ToC, but not in the text itself. (The used colour etc. are defined in my file, but then the MWE would be a bit big)

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,numbers=endperiod,titlepage,headinclude,
                footinclude=false,cleardoublepage=empty,abstractoff,
                BCOR=5mm,b5paper,fontsize=11pt, american,
                ]{scrreprt}

 \usepackage{caption}


 %lay-out of captions for figures and tables

 \usepackage{caption}

 \captionsetup{width=0.9\textwidth,format=plain,labelsep=quad,font=small,textfont={sl,{color=dark-gray}},labelfont={bf,{color=darker-gray}}}


 %lay-out of section titles 

 \usepackage{titlesec}

 \newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{10pt}}

 \titleformat{\chapter} [frame] {\bfseries\huge \centering \itshape}{{\color{dark-gray} \Huge \textasciii{Chapter \thechapter}}} {0.7cm} {}

 \titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries}{\Large \thesection. \hsp \textcolor{dark-gray}{||}\hsp}{6pt}{\Large \bfseries}

 \titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\color{darker-gray} \bfseries}{\color{darker-gray} \large \thesubsection.}{6pt}{\large \bfseries}



 %lay-out table of contents

 \usepackage{tocloft}

 \renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\color{darker-gray}}

 \renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{}

 \begin{document}

 \tableofcontents


 \include{Chapters/Introduction}



 \end{document}
```

Comment: KOMA, `titlesec` and `tocloft`, in one document? Really?

Comment: Yes, I know... that is not the best option, but I added in the process things I wanted and now it turns out is does not really work together

Comment: This worked really well :) Now I only want to change the lay-out of the ToC page (now the title 'Contents'  is in the same lay-out as a chapter titlen (words inside the box) instead of just the big word 'Contents'). I have to decide what I like better first ;)

Comment: And I added \cftpagenumbersoff{part} to suppress the page number in the ToC for parts (and also for chapters), but that is now not working anymore. Do you have a solution for this as well @esdd?

Comment: To reset the layout for ToC, LoF and LoT headers: `\BeforeTOCHead{\RedeclareSectionCommand{chapter}}`. To remove page numbers for parts in ToC: `\newcommand\gobble[1]{}` and `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[pagenumberformat=\gobble]{default}{part}` and the same with `chapter`.